# how to access values in a dictionary using reduce in swift?

Tags: swift

I got the `key` from the dictionary using `reduce` like by doing the following:

```
let namesAndScores = ["Anna": 2, "Brian": 2, "Craig": 8, "Donna": 6]

 let namesString = namesAndScores.reduce("",
 combine: { $0 + "\($1.0), " })
 print(namesString)
```

But I would like to know how to get the `value` from the `dictionary` using the `reduce` ?.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In `combine: { $0 + "\($1.0), " })`, you use `$1.0` to get the `key` from the `dictionary`, you also can use`$1.1` to get the `value`. Is this you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest you an easier way

```
let names = namesAndScores.keys.joinWithSeparator(", ")
//  Brian, Anna, Craig, Donna

let values = namesAndScores.values.map(String.init).joinWithSeparator(", ")
// 2, 2, 8, 6
```

### Update: code for reduce

```
 let values = String(namesAndScores.values.reduce("") { "\($0), \($1)"}.characters.dropFirst(2))
// 2, 2, 8, 6
```

Comment: Thanks, But I know the way you mentioned.

Comment: @AK1: Ok I will add the code for `reduce` then. One question: Why using reduce when there is an easier way?

Comment: That would be helpful. Nothing much learning swift and wanted to know how to do things.

Answer (score 5):

#### Accessing Value and Key w/ reduce

```
let dict = ["John": "", "Donna": ""]

let str = dict.reduce("") {
   $0 + "\($1.key) likes the color: \($1.value) "
}   
print(str) // Donna likes the color:  John likes the color:
```